# class is not a spark job and we are passsing the properties via SparkFiles

Tags: scala, log4j

The Class is not a spark job and we are passsing the properties via SparkFiles
also when use SparkFiles.get a file on driver in yarn-client or yarn-cluster, it 
will report file not found exception.

```
package xx.xxx.meatadata.ConfigurationParser

class FileValidatorConfiguration (confStr:String) extends ConfigurationValidator (confStr) {
   override val path="FileEvalutor"
   //necessary fields
   override val keys=Set("IN_FILE_LOCATION","IN_PROGRESS_FILE_LOCATION","REJECT_FILE_LOCATION","FILE_NAME_EXTRACT","TARGET_FILE_NAME")


   lazy val FS_PREFIX = getValue("FS_PREFIX").getOrElse("")
   lazy val IN_FILE_LOCATION=FS_PREFIX+getValue("IN_FILE_LOCATION").getOrElse("")
   lazy val IN_PROGRESS_FILE_LOCATION=FS_PREFIX+getValue("IN_PROGRESS_FILE_LOCATION").getOrElse("")
   lazy val REJECT_FILE_LOCATION=FS_PREFIX+getValue("REJECT_FILE_LOCATION").getOrElse("")
   lazy val PERIOD=getValue("PERIOD").getOrElse("")`enter code here`
   lazy val SOURCE=getValue("SOURCE").getOrElse("")
   lazy val FILE_NAME_EXTRACT=getValue("FILE_NAME_EXTRACT").getOrElse("")
   lazy val TARGET_FILE_NAME=getValue("TARGET_FILE_NAME").getOrElse("")
   lazy val SUBJECT=getValue("SUBJECT").getOrElse("")
}
```

is not a spark job and we are passsing the properties via SparkFiles
which is causing the exception

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.getRootDirectory(SparkFiles.scala:37)
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--files <comma-separated list of files>` option with spark submit to add local files to the class path when running your spark job